# React dependency warning from console log when using useEffect

Tags: reactjs

```
const [order, setOrder] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://localhost/services/${id}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setOrder(data))

}, [])
```

Comment: add id in useEffect dependence. `[id]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix missing dependency warning when using useEffect React Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `id` to the dependency array

```
const [order, setOrder] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://localhost/services/${id}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setOrder(data))

}, [ id ])
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry too much about the dependency warning, if you only want this to run when the component mounts then just ignore it, or turn it off.

Alternatively you can create your own effect called `useMount` that can act as a pseudo hook for when you only want things to run once, for example.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

/**
 * This is a pseudo hook that is designed to navigate around the react-hooks/exhaustive-deps rules in eslint without the need to
 * disable it entirely in the rest of the application. useMount guarantees that it will only run once when mounted, and
 * only requires the rules disabling for this definition.
 *
 * Use `useMount` in every place you would normally call `useEffect` with the intention of running it once.
 */
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
export const useMount = (mount: () => void) => useEffect(mount, []);

export default useMount;
```

Answer (score 0):

Extra http request from useEffect:

```
const fetchData = () => {
    fetch(`https://localhost/services/${id}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setOrder(data))
}

useEffect(() => {
    
    fetchData()
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  way , hope  it  will work

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = () => {
    fetch(`https://localhost/services/${id}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setOrder(data))
};
  fetchData ();
}, []);
```